# Magento 2: Custom Stock Status set manually

Tags: magento2, custom, stock-status

Is there possibility of adding a new "stock status" which would be independent of the stock. It would say something like "On order >14days" or "On order <7days"

They'd be changed only manually.

Answer (score 0):

create a product attribute called `order_stock_status` that will need to be set visible on front

and then on the product detail page, in the template where you want to display the custom stock message, you may use the code below or at least inspire yourself from it:

```
class ProductStockInfo extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    public function getProductStockStatus()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();

        if ($product->getOrderStockStatus()) {
            $stockMessage = $product->getOrderStockStatus();
        } else {
            if ($product->isAvailable()) {
                $stockMessage = 'In stock';
            } else {
                $stockMessage = 'Out of stock';
            }
        }

        return $stockMessage;
    }
}
```

this way, you can take over Magento stock status.

if the above works for you, the next thing is to hide the add to cart button from the `addtocart.phtml` template replacing `<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>` by `<?php if (!$product->getOrderStockStatus() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>`

same will apply in `products.phtml` template